# Continuous Functions and characteristic function

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\chi_A : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function for some subset $A$ of $X$. Show that $\chi_A$ is continuous at $p\in X$, if only if $p$ is not an element of the boundary of $A$.

Following the suggestion of Math1000, when $\chi_A$ is continuous then $p\notin\partial(A)$ I have some difficulty seeing the contradiction when $p\in\partial A$, I know that $p\in\partial A$ iff $p\in G$ (with $G$ open) such that $G\cap A \neq\varnothing$ and $p\in G$ open such that $G\cap A^c\neq\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some hints:

Suppose $\chi_A$ is continuous. Assume without loss of generality that $p\in A$. Let $U=\left(-\frac12, \frac12\right)$. Since $\chi_A$ is continuous, $\chi_A^{-1}(U)$ is open. Suppose $p\in\partial A$. Why does this lead to a contradiction?

Conversely, suppose $p\notin\partial A$. Assume without loss of generality that $p\in A$. Then $p\notin \overline{A^c}$, so there is a neighborhood of $p$ that does not intersect $A^c$. From there the proof is straightforward.

Comment: I have some difficulty seeing the contradiction when $p\in \partial A$, I know that $p\in \partial A$ iff p$\in$ G-open s.t G$\cap$A $\neq \emptyset$ and p$\in$ G-open s.t G$\cap A^c\neq \emptyset$

Comment: $\chi_A^{-1}(U)$ is an open set containing $p$. If $p\in\partial A$ then $\chi_A^{-1}(U)$ intersects both $A$ and $A^c$.

Comment: if $p\in\chi_A^{-1}(U) $ and $p\in A$, then $\chi_A(p)\in U$, as $p\in A$, the value of $\chi_A(p)$ is 1$\notin U$, Is the contradiction?

Comment: Yes. The argument is very similar if $p\notin A$.